# How to remove this faucet cartridge?

Tags: faucet

I have to remove a faucet cartridge and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. The outer chrome ring doesn't seem to unscrew, and there is no space to fit a wrench to get to the nut.

Do I need a special tool or am I missing something?

[image] [image]

Edit: I finally got it after spraying some WD40 on there. It is only the rounded chrome part that unscrews, definitely not easy to get a grip on a rounded part like that, I had to use a rubber band.

Comment: that red/orange ring looks like it might rotate clockwise a bit to free it

Comment: Any brand markings anywhere on the faucet? Perhaps on parts _below_ the counter top?

Comment: red/orange ring is all-but-certainly the anti-scald max temp setting

Comment: Brand seems to be "JALO", but I cant find any documentation, the Jalo line was discontinued.

Comment: @FreeMan The brand is Jalo

Comment: try turning the outer chrome collar

Comment: typically, only basic tools such as screwdriver and allen wrench are needed for swapping cartridge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks similar to some sink cartridges I've seen.  Those operate by inserting a cylinder with two protruding lugs onto slots and rotating.  The special tool is packaged with the new cartridge.

However, this one seems to have a hex nut keeping the cartridge in, so I'd try to unscrew the stainless cover, which should expose the brass hex nut you can see below.

The red  ring is an anti scald ring.

Comment: See edit, but that was it, the stainless cover was seized.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Detail from reflection in original picture]

I think the secret to the outer ring is there in the reflection (not well in focus.) It looks like a set-screw from here.

**Edit:** Updated detail to include the other possible thing that could be a set-screw per comment from @JMac

Comment: Good catch! +1!

Comment: The set screw may also be the other weird shape near the top, opposite what you show in the crop.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it after spraying some WD40 on there.

It is only the rounded chrome part that unscrews, definitely not easy to get a grip on a rounded part like that, I had to use a rubber band.

Answer (score 0):

According to [eHow](https://www.ehow.com/how_8538065_remove-jado-cartridge-nut.html) this is how you pull the cartridge for a Jalo brand faucet:

> 1. Shut off the water supply at the water main by turning the valve with a crescent wrench. (Or, simply turn the valve if you have a shutoff for each fixture)
> 2. Remove the plastic cap from the front of the faucet handle by lifting it up with a small flat head screwdriver.
> 3. Remove the screw from the handle with a Phillip's screwdriver.
> 4. Slide the handle off the valve stem, and remove the rubber gasket with the handle.
> 5. Place the special cartridge nut wrench over the Jado cartridge bonnet nut, and turn the nut counterclockwise to remove it.